# How do I plot a 1 dimensional error bar graph? - python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a one dimensional error bar graph for 3 different values, with 3 different errors associated. However, the function does not allow being passed a single array.
Basically, Im looking for a way to make this kind of plot
[image]

```
medias = [meanG, meanK, meanR]
desvs = [devst_G, devst_K, devst_R]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(medias, 'o', color= 'k')
plt.errorbar(medias, yerr= desvs, fmt='o', capsize= 0.5, capthick= 0.2, ecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: errorbar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not a minimal working example.

1st: Include import statements.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

2nd: Don't give us variables, that don't hold any values in them.

```py
# How am I supposed to plot anything? There are no numerical values.
medias = [meanG, meanK, meanR]
desvs = [devst_G, devst_K, devst_R]
```

3rd: Read how to use functions PROPERLY:

```py
# There are no y values here, only x values (medias)
plt.plot(medias, 'o', color= 'k')
```

4th: Here's your solution:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
yerr = [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y, 'o', color= 'k')
plt.errorbar(x,y, yerr= yerr, fmt='o', capsize= 0.5, capthick= 0.2, ecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

5th: I'd better get those sweet, sweet internet points for this, so accept the answer.